# Installing Ruby 1.9.2 with RVM doesn't work

Tags: ruby, bash, installation, rvm

When I do >rvm install 1.9.2 it all goes well.  Then I do >rvm use 1.9.2 and that goes well too.

When It comes to ruby -v though..

```
sam@sjones:~$ rvm install 1.9.2
/home/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.9.2-p136 - #fetching
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - #downloading ruby-1.9.2-p136, this may take a while depending on your connection...
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                               Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 8612k  100 8612k    0     0   562k      0  0:00:15  0:00:15 --:--:-- 1305k
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - #extracting ruby-1.9.2-p136 to /home/sam/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p136
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - #extracted to /home/sam/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p136
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - #configuring
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - #compiling
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - #installing
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - updating #rubygems for /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@global
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - updating #rubygems for /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - adjusting #shebangs for (gem).
ruby-1.9.2-p136 - #importing default gemsets (/home/sam/.rvm/gemsets/)
Install of ruby-1.9.2-p136 - #complete
sam@sjones:~$ rvm use 1.9.2
Using /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136
sam@sjones:~$ ruby -v
-bash: ruby: command not found
```

What on earth do I do? I've been trying for a few hours now

--Edit--

Here is my rvm info output:

```
 rvm info

 system:

 system:
    uname:       "Linux sjones 2.6.18-194.8.1.el5.028stab070.2 #1 SMP Tue Jul 6 14:55:39 MSD 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux"
 bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 3.2.39(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)"
 zsh:         " => not installed"

 rvm:
 version:      "rvm 1.2.2 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]"

 homes:
 gem:          "not set"
 ruby:         "not set"

 binaries:
 ruby:         ""
 irb:          "/usr/local/bin/irb"
 gem:          ""
 rake:         "/usr/bin/rake"

 environment:
 PATH:         "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/sam/.rvm/bin:/home/sam/.rvm/bin"
 GEM_HOME:     ""
 GEM_PATH:     ""
 MY_RUBY_HOME: ""
 IRBRC:        ""
 RUBYOPT:      ""
 gemset:       ""
```

Comment: Can you do `rvm info` and post the result here in an edit to your question please?

Comment: "What on earth do I do?" - You follow the instructions on [RVM's install page](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/). Read them, do them. Do the "Post Install" steps. Try the "Trouble Shooting Your Install" steps. This sort of pain can easily be avoid by reading before jumping in, and reading to the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

`rvm --default use 1.9.2`

--EDIT--
problem fixed, you need to run:
`[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"`

Comment: `/home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136 -v` works? your os =? `uname -a` = ?

Comment: uname -a: Linux sjones 2.6.18-194.8.1.el5.028stab070.2 #1 SMP Tue Jul 6 14:55:39 MSD 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux
  My OS is Debain and /home/sam.rvm..... returns that it is a directory

Comment: ur `rvm info` gives home: not set and ruby not set and environment all not set , that is the problem. I have a look for you...

Comment: do u get anything when u run `/home/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/ruby -v`? this is the place it should install to

Comment: only: sam@sjones:~$ /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136 -v
-bash: /home/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136: is a directory

Comment: ahh sorry lol it outputs : ruby 1.9.2p136 (2010-12-25 revision 30365) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: also try `rvm list` see if it is really installed by rvm?

Comment: Ahh right, I installed it using "bash < <( curl http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/releases/rvm-install-head )" from this guide: http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you

Comment: ok, try run `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm` directly on your console.  and then `ruby -v`, does it help?

Comment: sorry i missed quote at the end, i edit again lol
`[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"`

Comment: from that http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you 
it tells u to put it into .bashrc  or .bash_profile, but it wouldn't run it until u open another shell or login again. there for you need to run it so it will setup the PATH correctly...